# Can Android App shortcut on new process (after killing app from background) first go to splash screen and then to desired activity

Tags: android

I made four dynamic app shortcuts. When starting the app, on splash screen I have some task to be initialized from server and after that app is starting to show real screen for user. When i go back to home screen and enter app via shortcut it works as expected bcs splash screen made its init calls. When i kill app from background list and go to enter app again via shortcut it sends me to desired activity but the only problem is bcs of the logic in code, when there is a new process (and there is bcs app is killed from background) the app is first send to splash screen to make init call. Bcs of that app shortcut is not sent to desired activity. Is there a way on new process to send app shortcut first to splash and then to desired activity.

Comment: What is "app shortcut". Could you share your activity and the "task" you mentioned? It is hard to imagine what is going on and what you are trying to solve without sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem just by sending shortcut intent first to splashscreen to make init calls from server and then after init is made further to desired activity.